# submodules of the exterior algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Let $A_{n,q}$ be the exterior algebra of a vector space of dimension $n$ over the finite field $F_q$.

Let $a_{n,q}$ be the number of submodules of $A_{n,q}$ (meaning submodules of the $A_{n,q}$-module $A_{n,q}$).

> Question: What is $a_{n,q}$?

For $q=2$, $a_{n,q}$ starts with 3,7,47,...